# Django logging does not work with django shell

Tags: python, django, logging

I have logging set up in my Django app to log to both stdout and a file.

When I run my django app normally (`./manage.py runserver`) the logs are updated as expected. Here is an example that successfully logs when i visit the url for the view below:

```
# views.py

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')

def test(request):
    logger.error("test")
```

However, when I run `./manage.py shell` and run the following commands the log is not updated:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.error('test')
```

Here is my logging setup in settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '../debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Do I have to do something extra to get logging to work within the shell?

Comment: Edit your question to show us the logging code that does work when you use `runserver`, and the logging setup in `settings.py`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I updated my question. Your comment seems to imply that logging should work in the shell if it works in runserver, because you are trying to see where I have misconfigured my settings. Can you confirm that logging should work in the shell?

Comment: @BUZZY this is not a dup of that question. I am successful in logging to the console. If you read through that question and mine, you would see that I am properly configuring the `'loggers'` dict with a logger matching the name I am calling

Comment: @rawbeans try to change console's handler stream on sys.stderr

Comment: I had a very close problem where the log I was waiting for was activated from a middleware. But the shell does not use the middlewares for the HTTP requests. However, logging created explictly in the shell was already working for me ; so your problem may be more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine in the shell. It does for me, with the same logging configuration as you (except that I used `'ext:://sys.stdout'` instead of `sys.stdout`, as I didn't have `sys` imported in `settings.py`.

```
django20 vinay@ubuntu:/tmp/foo$ tail -25 foo/settings.py 
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '../debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

django20 vinay@ubuntu:/tmp/foo$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import logging; logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
>>> logger.error('foo')
foo
>>> logger.warning('bar')
bar
>>> logger.info('baz')
baz
>>> logger.debug('boz')
>>> 

django20 vinay@ubuntu:/tmp/foo$ more ../debug.log 
foo
bar
baz
```

This was using a fresh virtualenv with a Django 2.0 installation, but it should work exactly the same with older versions of Django.

Answer (score 2):

during working with django-shell in Pycharm i was facing the same issue. There are two ways to solve it.

1. When you django-shell is started go and import it manually:

   import logging; l=logging.getLogger('django.db.backends');l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG);l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
2. Or if you are using the Pycharm professional edition like me than you can add this import on console startup you can see in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/console-django-console.html official docs.
   To do this, go to your
   **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Django Console for Windows and Linux**

**PyCharm | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Django Console for macOS**

and add this import command on console startup.